# Adding a subview to a class compiled without ARC

Tags: automatic-ref-counting, uamodalpanel

My app uses ARC, but I'm using a library that is compiled without ARC, specifically UAModalPanel. I'd like to add a subview to one of the views of this class, is there anything special I have to do to make sure that that subview is retained and then deallocated when no longer needed? (I don't keep a reference to that subview in my main code after its been added)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as your code and the library's code follow [KVC naming conventions](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/Compliant.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002172-BAJEAIEE), ARC and non-ARC are compatible and you do not need to worry about exchanging objects between modules compiled with one or the other. ARC is designed explicitly to be transparent in this way. It simply inserts the retains and releases that you would have added yourself if you were very carefully following the rules. It does have some optimization tricks when it knows all the code involved in a method call is ARC, but it can automatically detect this at runtime and will take out the optimization if it is calling non-ARC code.

Comment: Awesome thx! Does this mean i could even subclass a class from this library, and use ARC in that subclass?

Comment: Absolutely. ARC can be used on a per-compile-unit basis (i.e. each .m file), and is designed to interoperate transparently with other compile units that do or do not use ARC, as long as you follow the naming rules. It does not matter what object hierarchy those compile units implement.